# Swagger + Spring show csv as example

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csv

I have added a `AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter` to Spring that looks the following:

```java
public class SongConverter extends AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter<Song> {

    public SongConverter() {
        super(new MediaType("text", "csv"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(@NonNull Song song, Type type, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        try (var writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputMessage.getBody())) {
            new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<>(writer).withSeparator(',').build().write(song);
        } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException ex) {
            log.error("Error while writing song to csv", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Type type, Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return super.canWrite(clazz, mediaType) && clazz == Song.class;
    }
}
```

And then in my Swagger Docs I get both fields in my Swagger generated code
Here is an image:
[image: da img], however the CSV example doesn't change and remains of type JSON. When I added XML it was correct and changed accordingly.

For reference here is my Config Bean:

```java
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer configurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void configureContentNegotiation(@NonNull ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.parameterName("mediaType").ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .mediaType("csv", new MediaType("text", "csv"))
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }

        @Override
        public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            converters.add(new SongConverter());
            //converters.add(new SongsConverter());
        }
    };
}
```

Is there something I'm missing? I'm aware of the workaround with overriding the default of the API, but that solution seems rather sketchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with "swagger annotations" like so:

```java
package com.example.springboot3openapi;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.ExampleObject;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SomeController {

  @Operation(summary = "Get some", responses = {
    @ApiResponse(
        description = "Successful Operation",
        responseCode = "200",
        content = {
          @Content(
              mediaType = "application/json",
              schema = @Schema(implementation = SomeObject.class)
          ),
          @Content( // !
              mediaType = "text/csv",
              schema = @Schema(implementation = SomeObject.class),
              examples = { // !!
                @ExampleObject(value = "foo;bar\nstring;string\n") // <- your csv string here
              }
          )
        }
    ),
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Authentication Failure", content = @Content) // ,...
  })
  @GetMapping(value = "some", produces = {"text/csv", "application/json"})
  public ResponseEntity<SomeObject> somePost() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new SomeObject("Hello", "World"));
  }
}
```

Produces UI like:

[image: screenshot]

This is a openapi-v3 solution, for v2 please replace with the according annotations. Tested with sprin-boot:3.0.0 (-> https://springdoc.org/v2/) and spring-boot:2.7.6 (-> https://springdoc.org/). #

Comment: side note: i implemented&configured http-message-converter like yours (+ `com.opencsv:opencsv:5.7.1`), but it "rearranged" the columns ;(;(

Comment: I tried to come up with a more generic solution like `@Bean
  OperationCustomizer opCust() {
    return (op, method) -> {
      ApiResponse ar = op.getResponses().get("200");
      if (ar != null) {
        Content content = ar.getContent();
        for (Map.Entry<String, MediaType> e : content.entrySet()) {
          String key = e.getKey();
          MediaType mt = e.getValue();
          if ("text/csv".equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
            try {
              StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();...`

Comment: it triggers! ... but the problem is: 1. it is buggy ..(it affects all media types, not only "text/csv") 2. The backend delivers (by default) empty example objects (the rest is taken care by swagger-ui!;(;(